# How to disable/enable multiple upload buttons with multiple checkboxes

Tags: javascript, html

I am a beginner and am having trouble making my code work. I want to enable/disable a file upload button by clicking a check box. the code works fine when I have only 1 upload button and one check box but it does not when I have more then one. Can anyone please help?

[this is JSFiddle preview](https://jsfiddle.net/sc6ksu0m/75) .

html code

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="confirm">
</label>

<input type="file" class="style5" id="abstract" name="abstract" disabled onchange="ValidateSingleInput(this);"/>
<br>        

<label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="confirmp">
</label>

<input type="file" class="style5" id="poster" name="poster" disabled onchange="ValidateSingleInput(this);"/>
    <span class="style5"><br>        

        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="confirmr">
        </label>

        <input type="file" class="style5" id="resume" name="resume" disabled onchange="ValidateSingleInput(this);" />

        <span class="style5">
```

javascript code

```
window.onload = function() {
    var checker = document.getElementById('confirm');
    var sbm = document.getElementById('abstract');

    checker.onchange = function () {
        if(this.checked) {
            sbm.disabled = false;
        } 
        else {
            sbm.disabled = true;

        }
    };
};

window.onload = function() {
    var checker = document.getElementById('confirmp');
    var sbm = document.getElementById('poster');

    checker.onchange = function () {
        if(this.checked) {
            sbm.disabled = false;
        } 
        else {
            sbm.disabled = true;

        }
    }; 
};

window.onload = function() {
    var checker = document.getElementById('confirmr');
    var sbm = document.getElementById('resume');

    checker.onchange = function () {
        if(this.checked) {
            sbm.disabled = false;
        } 
        else {
            sbm.disabled = true;
        }
    }; 
};
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code here as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many window.onload so only the last one is active by the end of the script. One window.onload is enough and then you can run all your functions together. Try this updated [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sc6ksu0m/76/).

```
window.onload = function() {
var checker = document.getElementById('confirm');
var sbm_abstract = document.getElementById('abstract');
var checkerp = document.getElementById('confirmp');
var sbm_poster = document.getElementById('poster');
var checkerr = document.getElementById('confirmr');
var sbm_resume = document.getElementById('resume');


checker.onchange = function () {
    if(this.checked) {
        sbm_abstract.disabled = false;
    } 
    else {
        sbm_abstract.disabled = true;

    }
} ;



checkerp.onchange = function () {
    if(this.checked) {
        sbm_poster.disabled = false;
    } 
    else {
        sbm_poster.disabled = true;

    }
}; 

checkerr.onchange = function () {
    if(this.checked) {
        sbm_resume.disabled = false;
    } 
    else {
        sbm_resume.disabled = true;

    }
}; 

};
```

I renamed the variables to not override each other and i initialize all your functions in one window.onload event.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you write a new `window.onload = function() { ... };` you are overwriting the previous function that was going to be executed when the window loads, and that's why only the last check box works.

So, to solve the problem, make sure you put your code inside the same `onload`.

This should work:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var checker = document.getElementById('confirm');
    var sbm = document.getElementById('abstract');

    checker.onchange = function () {
        if(this.checked) {
            sbm.disabled = false;
        } 
        else {
            sbm.disabled = true;
        }
    };

    var checkerp = document.getElementById('confirmp');
    var sbmp = document.getElementById('poster');

    checkerp.onchange = function () {
        if(this.checked) {
            sbmp.disabled = false;
        } 
        else {
            sbmp.disabled = true;
        }
    }; 

    var checkerr = document.getElementById('confirmr');
    var sbmr = document.getElementById('resume');

    checkerr.onchange = function () {
        if(this.checked) {
            sbmr.disabled = false;
        } 
        else {
            sbmr.disabled = true;
        }
    }; 
};
```

Comment: Sorry, now I have another problem: if the checkbox is unchecked I want the file on record to stay but every time after submit the file is getting erased from the database. Can someone help please? My code is at [JSFiddle] (http://jsfiddle.net/sc6ksu0m/83) 83

Answer (score 0):

You only need one `window.onload`.

Try this:

```
   window.onload = function () {

      var checker = document.getElementById('confirm'),
      sbm = document.getElementById('abstract'),
      checker2 = document.getElementById('confirmp'),
      sbm2 = document.getElementById('poster'),
      checker3 = document.getElementById('confirmr'),
      sbm3 = document.getElementById('resume');

      checker.onchange = function () {
           enableDisable(checker, sbm);
      };

      checker2.onchange = function () {
           enableDisable(checker2, sbm2);
      };

      checker3.onchange = function () {
           enableDisable(checker3, sbm3);
      };

      function enableDisable(target, btn) {
           btn.disabled = target.checked ? false : true;
      };

};
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sc6ksu0m/78/)

Comment: Sure no problem @Nargis, glad I could help. I refactored your code a bit and updated the fiddle